# c++ Start an OMP thread in a derived function

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Let's say I have one base class with a virtual function with two OMP threads :

```
class Parent {
 public:
  Parent() {}
  ~Parent() {}
  virtual void f() {
  #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
  #pragma omp section
      {
         // do_something_1();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         // do_something_2();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a derived class like this :

```
class Child : public Parent {
 public:
  Child() {}
  ~Child() {}
  void f() {
    Parent::f();
    // Other thread OMD
  }
}
```

I would like to have at the end the two threads from the Parent class and the thread from the Child running but it is not working. Is it even possible with this design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the OpenMP directives are inside the Parent's virtual function and so
are not seen in your derived class. As you call the parent code in the derived class
this suggests two possible solutions, both have advantages and disadvantages.

Version 1 keeps Parent's operations private but can only be extended one extra
level.

```
class Parent {
 public:
  void f() {
  #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
  #pragma omp section
      {
         // do_something_1();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         // do_something_2();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         this->f_impl();
      }
    }
  }
  private:
    virtual void f_impl() {}; // do nothing placeholder

}

class Child : public Parent {
  private:
    void f_impl() override;
}
```

OR

Version 2 can be extended indefinitely but needs to expose each Parent's internals.

```
class Parent {
 public:
  virtual void f() {
  #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl1();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl2();
      }
    }
  }
  protected:
    void f_impl1();
    void f_impl2();

}

class Child : public Parent {
 public:
  virtual void f() {
  #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl1();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl2();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl3();
      }
    }
  }
  protected:
    void f_impl3();
}

class Child2 : public Child {
 public:
  virtual void f() {
  #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl1();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl2();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl3();
      }
  #pragma omp section
      {
         f_impl4();
      }
    }
  }
  protected:
    void f_impl4();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I chose option 1 and it worked like a charm !

Comment: You can also use tasks as per @Zulan's answer with option 1. That makes it even more flexible as you can move the `#pragma omp task` into the derived function allowing you to call `#pragma omp task` multiple times in your derived function.

Answer (score 0):

In such a context, I would rather recommend using tasks, and ensuring that everything is executed within a parallel context, e.g.:

```
// prepare the parallel context somewhere outside
#pragma omp parallel
#pargma omp single
run();


class Parent {
 public:
  Parent() {}
  ~Parent() {}
  virtual void f() {
    #pragma omp task
    {
      // do_something_1();
    }
    // do_something_2();
    #pragma omp taskwait
    // It's not nice for reasoning about code to keep tasks running here
  }
}
class Child : public Parent {
 public:
  Child() {}
  ~Child() {}
  void f() {
    // swap the order in the code
    // to account for taskwait at the end of paraent::f
    #pragma omp task
    {
      // Other thread OMD
    }
    Parent::f();
    // if you feel like it, you can also add a taskwait here
  }
}
```

As you can see, if you ensure a parallel context (but use single execution of code) in your application, then you can easily use tasks to achieve parallelization across derived calls. However, be careful with leaving executing tasks at the end of a function call as this can be dangerous. Make sure that the caller knows when he has to `taskwait` to ensure that the operation is complete - or swap it such that the caller executes a task in parallel to whatever the callee does.

It would also be possible to create the parallel context on demand if no thread team exists, but I think that is less clean and more dangerous.